# Axios GET response data correct, but Promise Pending to variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, sql-server

I have a back end server running that requests data from a database following an Axios GET request.

```
app.get('/calendars', (req, res) => {
    //query database for userlist
    sql.connect(config, err => {
        // ... error checks
        console.log("err1-" + err)
        // Query
        new sql.Request().query('SELECT full_name AS "id", full_name AS "label", CAST(0 AS BIT) AS "readonly", CAST(1 AS BIT) AS "active" FROM [User];', (err, result) => {
            // ... error checks
            console.dir(result.recordset)
            res.status(200).json(result.recordset)
        })
    })
})
```

My front end GET request logs out the response.data correctly, but when I try to log the returned response.data after assigning to a variable I get a Promise pending. I've looked online, I definitely have an "Await" and I've tried a .then but get the same result.

```
async function getCalendars() {
    try {
      const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/calendars');
      console.log(response.data)
       return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

var defaultCalendars = getCalendars()
console.log(defaultCalendars);
```

[image: Console Output]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

---

Further information following @evolutionbox comment.

```
async function getCalendars() {
    try {
      return await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/calendars');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

const defaultCalendars = getCalendars().then(result => console.log(result))

console.log(defaultCalendars);
```

As originally, the Line 107 - console.log(result) displays the data, but the Line 109 - console.log(defaultCalendars) is again Promise {}.

[image: console output 2]

---

Added await getCalendars() within an async function.

```
var defaultCalendars;

async function run() {
    defaultCalendars = await getCalendars()
}

async function getCalendars() {
    try {
      return await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/calendars');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

run();

console.log(defaultCalendars);
```

Comment: You need to await `getCalendars()` or use `.then` e.g. `getCalendars().then(result => console.log(result))`.

Comment: @evolutionxbox thank you for your response, also in response to the propose answer below, using await in this way gives me "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules". Please see edit to original question showing result of adding the .then =>.

Comment: That's because [await is a reserved word that only works inside async functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await#the_await_keyword). Put it inside an async function and use await, or use `.then`

Comment: @evolutionxbox thanks again. I've amended my question to show the code with the await added within an async function. The console now reads undefined for console.log(defaultCalendars). And my previous modification showed the use of .then and the result I received.

Comment: Please read the other linked articles? You cannot access async values like that. They can only be accessed once awaited inside async functions, or within a `.then` callback. [See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Answer (score -1):

It would work if you use await with the variable.

```
const response = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/calendars');
const data= await response.data;
console.log(data)
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you for the response. If I use await like this I get the following error "Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules". My example code is written directly in calendar.js not within any methods.